# Get count of child elements from one instance of a class

Tags: jquery, tumblr

I'm customising a tumblr blog, and I want to apply certain styles and rules depending on the number of photos present in a photoset.  What I'm not sure how to get a count of the child elements present in each post when each post has the same class.  If this is the sort of code that is generated by tumblr:

```
<div class="photoset">
     <img />
     <img />
</div>

<div class="photoset">
     <img />
     <img />
     <img />
</div>
```

How do I get jQuery to return the number of  elements in the first and second instances (i.e. 2 and 3)?

I've tried using `$('.photoset img').length();` and that gives me a total count of all  elements present (i.e. 5 in this case).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Scott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cycle through each photoset item and count it's images separately and then do whatever you want with that information at that point in the code:

```
$(".photoset").each(function(index, elem) {
    var numImages = $(this).find("img").length;
    // do whatever processing you wanted to with numImages here
});
```

If you want to put these counts in an array, you could do it like this:

```
var imgCountArray = $(".photoset").map(function() {
    return($(this).find("img").length)
}).get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below,

```
var imgCounts = [];

$('.photoset').each (function () {
  imgCounts.push($(this).find('img').length);
});
```

Now,

```
imgCounts[0] = 2 //first divs img count
imgCounts[1] = 3 //second divs img count
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can go about this.

First, you could use `.each()` to cycle through each `.photoset`:

```
$('.photoset').each( function() {
   var num = $(this).find('img').length;
   // Do something based on num
});
```

Or, use `.eq()` or `:eq()` to select a certain one:

`var num = $('.photoset:eq(1) img').length;`

`var num = $('.photoset').eq(1).find('img').length;`

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
$(".photoset").each(function(i, photoset) {
  photoset = $(photoset); 
  var numImages = photoset.children().length;
  // or var numImages = photoset.find("img").length; for only images

  if (numImages === 2) {
    // your code
  }
  if (numImages === 3) {
    // your code
  }

  // or just comparing whether greater or lower
  if (numImages > 2) {
    // your code
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the way I wanted to go with it once I'd learned how to get the count - it's a massive help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.photoset:first img').length
```

and

```
$('.photoset:last img').length
```

Comment: This won't help much if there are more than two photosets.